# Javascript help, can use jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I've got a HTML link

```
<a href="http://jquery.com">Click</a>
```

I want to show a dialog box to ask if the user want to go to that website, if user clicked no, then does nothing, just close the dialog box; if clicked yes, then go to that link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are okay with native alert boxes, then you can use confirm:

```
$(function() {
   $("a .confirm").click(function(e) {
      return confirm("Are you sure?");
   });
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="http://jquery.com" class="confirm" />
```

This will add this functionality to all links with the confirm class. :-)

Comment: This looks does not work here.. It went to the new link even if I cliecked no

Answer (score 0):

This is just off the top of my head and not actually checked for accuracy but it's a close approximation of what you'll want to do.

```
$("a").click(function() {
    return (confirm("Are you sure you want to do this?"));
});
```

[JS Confirm](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptconfirm.php)

[jQuery Click](http://api.jquery.com/click/)